# Overide max-width of body tag

Tags: html, css, menu, width, footer

I have been trying to figure this out for some time but I cant seem to understand whats happening.

So basically I have a max width on my body tag of 900px. I would like a footer div inside the body to be 100% of the browser window. I have tried the using  width:100vw but it behaves unexpectedly and the div starts from the left border of the body (not browser window). So then I positioned the div absolutely to left:0 and right 0. The problem arises when I try to center the content within the div with margin:0 auto. It does not get centered.

The result that Im trying to achieve is to have a footer menu with multiple columns of  links that expands to fit the full width of the window.

```html
 <body class="minwidth900">
     <footer>

        <div class="full_browser_width">
         <div class="width100% margin0auto">


               <ul class="floatleft">
                  <li>link1</li>
                  <li>link2</li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="floatleft">
                  <li>link1</li>
                  <li>link2</li>
               </ul>

         </div>
       </div>
     </footer>
    </body>
```

I have tried my best to figure this out and searched a lot for an answer on the net. So please be kind if this is an easy fix.
Thanks for your time and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you shouldn't make the body 900px, but use a wrapper that has a width of 900px

Comment: yes try what @Mainz007 said and if you still have issues create a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks guys. Created a wrapper class and just placed the footer outside it. Worked like a charm. Cheers